# Defining plane induced homography for image manipulation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to artificially manipulate a 2D image using a rigid 3D transformation (T). Specifically, I have an image and I want to transform using T it to determine the image if captured from a different location.

Here's what I have so far:

- The problem reduces to determining the plane-induced homography (Hartley and Zisserman Chapter 13) - without camera calibration matrices this is H = R-t*n'/d.

I am unsure, however, how to define **n** and *d*. I know that they help to define the world plane, but I'm not sure how to define them in relation to the first image plane (e.g. the camera plane of the original image).

Please advise! Thanks! K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "first image plane": the camera's?

The vector n and the scalar d define the equation of the plane defining the homography:
n X + d = 0, or, in coordinates, n_x * x + n_y * y + n_z * z + d = 0, for every point X = (x, y, z) belonging to the plane.

There are various ways to estimate the homography. For example, you can map a quadrangle on the plane to a rectangle of known aspect ratio.

Or you can estimate the locations of vanishing points (this comes handy when you have, say, an image of a skyscraper, with nice rows of windows). In this case, if p and q are the homogeneous coordinates of the vanishing points of two orthogonal lines on a plane in the scene, then normal to the plane in camera coordinates is simply given by (p X q) / (|p| |q|)